# File corruption issue with repo - randomly replacing underscore with uppercase O

Tags: android, linux, git, corruption, kvm

I have a rather peculiar corruption issue, let's first list the circumstances:

Host hardware:

- Supermicro SuperServer A+ 2022G-URF
- only 1 CPU installed: AMD Opteron 6348
- RAM: 4x Samsung 8GB DDR3 PC3-12800 CL11 (M393B1K70DH0-CK0) = 32GB
- HDD: 4x Seagate Constellation ES.3 SAS 2.0 1TB (ST1000NM0023) as system HDDs (Health: Good)
- LSI MegaRaid 9260-8i RAID Controller with BBU (Health: Good)
- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 Server

The HDDs are configured in a RAID10 (32kb stripe size) with: Disk Cache enabled, Write back if good BBU, IO-Access: Direct. ECC is enabled and working in the System-BIOS

The Server is used as a VM host (kvm + libvirt), one VM is a buildbot for automatic Android source sync & build.

The VM is configured as follows:

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>buildbot</name>
  <uuid>long-uuid-that-is-of-no-interest-here</uuid>
  <description>buildbot</description>
  <memory unit='KiB'>14729216</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>14729216</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static' cpuset='2-11'>10</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-1.5'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
    <bootmenu enable='yes'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact'>
    <model fallback='allow'>Opteron_G5</model>
    <vendor>AMD</vendor>
    <feature policy='require' name='perfctr_core'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='skinit'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='perfctr_nb'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='mmxext'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='osxsave'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='vme'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='topoext'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='fxsr_opt'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='bmi1'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='ht'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='cr8legacy'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='ibs'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='wdt'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='extapic'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='osvw'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='nodeid_msr'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='tce'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='cmp_legacy'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='lwp'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='monitor'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm-spice</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='writethrough' io='native'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/disk.img'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='scsi' index='0' model='virtio-scsi'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='direct'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:XX:XX:XX'/>
      <source dev='eth0' mode='bridge'/>
      <model type='e1000'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes'/>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Installed is Ubuntu 14.04 server as well.

Now comes the rather strange issue:

Usually everything works fine. (repo init && repo sync && compile)
Rarely though, the sync is corrupting data on checkouts. This data is not recognized as corrupted by git or repo (which in turn uses git, so no surprise there). It's also a very very specific corruption (I would go so far to call it a simple string replace).

Example:

```
external/iproute2/tc/q_cbq.c:208: error: undefined reference to 'getOrate'
external/iproute2/tc/q_cbq.c:214: error: undefined reference to 'getOrate'
external/iproute2/tc/q_cbq.c:69: error: undefined reference to 'getOrate'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

getOrate (uppercase O not a 0) is supposed to be get_rate.

Git doesn't recognize this as a change or corruption (`git status`, `git diff` and `git fsck --full` are all clean) unless once changed to get_rate and back to getOrate. Git also doesn't notice or correct it with `git reset --hard`, `git reset --hard m/branch`, `git fetch remote && git reset --hard remote/branch`. This is not the only file it is happening in, it is just an example. It happens in random files with random occurrences, even only 1 time in a file and leaving other get_rate occurrences alone. A fresh checkout on a virgin system already fell prey to this.

However if the git repository is cloned separately, without repo, on the same or another machine, the issue is not present.

Various HDD emulators / storage formats and IO/Cache policies have already been tried. The RAM was checked multiple times for the guest and the host, as well as the HDDs, no errors could be found. The server and the VM have both been re-setup multiple times, the issue re-appears sooner or later.

Repo version:

`VERSION = (1, 21)`

git version:

`git version 1.9.1`

Google didn't come up with any solutions (it's rather hard to google for a s/_/O corruption issue) and after almost a week of error checking the hardware, configuration cables, module fit, etc etc... I am at the end of my wisdom.

Any pointer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For what it's worth, `_` is ASCII `5F` and `O` is ASCII `4F`, so this is a single-bit change (something clearing bit `0x10` in one particular byte).  For it to behave like this is very odd though.

Comment: @torek Thank you! That actually was worth a lot :) Especially the keyword "single-bit" + corruption helped me finding the solution, see the answer I just posted and accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @torek (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) I found a mention of a single-bit corruption issue in LSI's firmware update logs for .120 - previous firmware did not recognize disk cache corruption under certain conditions.

Since I already had to update it, I updated it to the newest available: .130. (this had to be done step-by-step, current->.120->.130 because .130 was not recognized by my controllers ancient firmware, causing a 'corrupted firmware' issue)

After the firmware updates I finally got some SENSE errors:

```
05/25/14 12:07:46: EVT#00420-05/25/14 12:07:46: 113=Unexpected sense: PD 0c(e0xfc/s2) Path 4433221101000000, CDB: 1a 08 c8 00 ff 00, Sense: 5/24/00
05/25/14 12:07:46: Raw Sense for PD c: 70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 24 00 00 00 00 00
05/25/14 12:07:46: PdWriteCacheSet: Error=2 issuing MODE SENSE to pd=0c
```

Finally, after switching out the affected drives (!three! of the new drives were affected) the corruption issue disappeared as magically as it appeared :)
So I guess the disk cache was damaged/faulty on those drives, which caused a single bit error.
I RMA'd them yesterday, but the 3 spares I had lying around already work perfectly (till now, trying not to jinx my luck ^^).

I am going to switch the 4th one out too, as a preventive measure, once the RMA-replacements arrive since it is from the same batch as the others that had this peculiar issue.

.

EDIT:

Hint:
The more detailed, technical, log of LSI controllers can be accessed via `MegaCli64 -fwtermlog -dsply -aX` (X = adapter id)